# Script to find database logical details

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on this SQL script to list out database logical record details but not able to successfully join tables.

Trying to list all below columns but stumbles at displaying `file_id` (datafile id).

All help and suggestions are really appreciated.

Columns required:

```
 owner, segment_name, partition_name, file_id, segment_type, 
 extent count, size_k (space occupied by object)
```

I think I need to join `dba_segment`, `dba_extents` & `dba_tablespaces` views but it's not working out...

```
SELECT 
    dbs.owner, dbs.segment_name, dbs.partition_name, dbe.file_id, 
    dbs.segment_type, dbs.extents "Extent count" , dbs.bytes/1024 "size_k" 
FROM dba_segments dbs, dba_extents dbe, dba_tablespaces tbs 
WHERE 
    dbs.tablespace_name = dbe.tablespace_name 
    and dbe.tablespace_name = tbs.tablespace_name 
    and tbs.contents = 'PERMANENT'
```

Above doesn't give correct result.... looks like table join or something is wrong...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: I am running this query against oracle11g... idea is to list segments details but also list datafile id which gets tricky since each segments have more extents in dba_extents... so join gets  complicated.

Comment: thanks marc_s for that link.. I never thought this type of join was so old.. reading your link now..

Comment: marc_s still not able to join correctly... do you have any suggestions?

Comment: 'stumbles at displaying' and 'doesn't give correct results' are not helpful diagnostic info. I'm not sure why you're joining to `dba_tablespace` at all since you aren't displaying any fields from it and are unlikely to have any objects in non-permanent tablespaces; but all your joins are only on `tablespace_name`, not - for example - `owner`, `segment_name` and `partition_name`. You're getting close to a cartesian join. You're also getting the file_id for every extent, but showing the segment size against each one; if you have to go to that detail, shouldn't you be showing the extent sizes?

Comment: Oh and marc_s, this post is tagged with oracle not sqlserver. So select statements with the old joins are not deprecated here by my knowledge if you look at the examples that oracle gives: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2066652
They use the old joins in there own examples.

Comment: yes alex, nightfox79 ..you both guys right... I just queried dba_extents and all is good

Comment: For inspiration, you may look into "Senora" at sourceforge. It provides some space related queries (though not exactly the one you asked for). Disclaimer: I am the author of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Choose the columns you need.  Notice that the partition_name can be null. There are a segment.header_file and an extent file_id which can differ. The segment extent_count = max(extent_id)+1 for the segment partition since the extent_ids start at zero each segment partition. The segment bytes = sum(extent.bytes).

```
SELECT seg.owner, seg.segment_name, seg.partition_name, 
      seg.header_file, seg.bytes / 1024 AS segment_kb, seg.EXTENTS AS extent_count, 
      seg.tablespace_name, ext.extent_id, ext.file_id, ext.bytes / 1024 as extent_kb
FROM dba_segments seg
JOIN dba_extents ext
  ON seg.owner = ext.owner
 AND seg.segment_name = ext.segment_name
 AND (seg.partition_name = ext.partition_name OR seg.partition_name IS NULL)
ORDER BY seg.owner, seg.segment_name, seg.partition_name, ext.extent_id
 ;
```