# How to know tablespace name and datafilename associated with a table in oracle11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a user in my sysdba, and created a table in this user named as 'sampletable1', now I want that sql query to select the tablespace name , database file associated with table “sampletable1”.

Comment: A table can be spread over several tablespaces (in case of partition) and a tablespace can be spread over several database files. There is no fix one-to-one relation.

Comment: Why do you want to know? If you want to know so that you can backup the correct data files then do not do it that way (use RMAN and tell it to backup the table rather than going about it backwards). If it is academic curiosity for no practical reason then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16107997/1509264

Comment: _"I have a user in my sysdba"_    What do you mean, "in my sysdba".   SYSDBA is a special privilege. It is not a container of any kind. There is nothing "in" it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you read comments.

Anyway: for a simple case - an "ordinary" table created in my schema:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create table stack_test (id number);

Table created.
```

you might run such a query:

```
SQL> connect sys@pdb1 as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select f.file_name,
  2         f.tablespace_name,
  3         t.table_name
  4  from dba_data_files f join dba_tables t on t.tablespace_name = f.tablespace_name
  5  where t.owner = 'SCOTT'
  6    and t.table_name = 'STACK_TEST';

FILE_NAME                                           TABLESPACE_NAME TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------- --------------- ---------------
C:\ORACLE\ORACLE_21XE\ORADATA\XE\XEPDB1\USERS01.DBF USERS           STACK_TEST

SQL>
```

Comment: That will return all files associated with the tablespace the table is in, even if the table doesn't use them. Also, t.tablespace_name isn't populated for partitioned tables.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that a table's data could be spread across many files, or it might not be associated with any storage if it is empty. Also, it's not clear what you mean by *in my sysdba* - hopefully you didn't create or change anything in the SYS schema. Anyway, you can try something like the following:

```
select x.segment_name, f.file_name
from   dba_extents x
       join dba_data_files f on f.file_id = x.file_id 
where  x.owner = user  -- or whatever schema owns the table
and    x.segment_name = 'YOURTABLENAME';
```

A bit of history: many years ago there used to be a technique for spreading i/o across multiple disk drives, whereby you would add files from different disk groups to a tablespace and use multiple `alter table xyz allocate extent (datafile path/to/file.dat)` or some such (it's been a while) commands, such that the table's physical data was spread across multiple storage devices, the hope being that if the table was accessed by multiple sessions concurrently this would spread the load across the available hardware. Nowadays data files tend to be allocated automatically, or else they are on a SAN which is itself a logical volume and not one physical filesystem anyway, not to mention heavily cached, and this kind of micromanagement is pointless.